# understanding over an example presented in Engel's book

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

> Each of the numbers $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ is 1 or -1, and we have $$ S=a_1a_2a_3a_4+a_2a_3a_4a_5+...+a_na_1a_2a_3$$

Engel has written that if we replace any $a_i$ by $-a_i$ , then $S$ does not change $mod 4$; but I didn't get why.Could someone help me explain this?

Comment: Found this. He also states "since four cyclically adjacent terms change their sign." Also, he proceeds to give a casework too. Is this not clear enough?

Comment: You only need to consider 4 of the terms in that summation. If their summation is 4 or -4, then it changes the sum by 8 which is 0 mod 4. If their summation is 2 or -2 then it changes the sum by 4 which is 0 mod 4. If their summation is 0 then no change.